# How to identify emergent Eau de cologne mint flowering stem?

Tags: identification, flowering, mint

How to identify an emerging flowering stem and prune it before it bolts?
I am new to growing, I had seen pictures of already flowered mints.
I googled and read and decided perhaps it is a good decision I shouldn't allow it to flower lest it wastes its energy too.
I spotted 3 thicker very purplish stems, unlike usual very smooth (to touch) stems not as dark purplish.
Moreover, the leaves(?) don’t look like normal leaves. They are rounder, have more pinky veins(obvious from underside).
Leaf tip look unusual. The stem sprout strongly all the way out. With the "(pale dark green pinky roundish) leaves" at all intervals remaining tiny hardly growing bigger.

If these are flowering stems, is it advisable to cut them off? Cut where?
Can boil water chew eat the stems or not? They look rich in red pigment.
[image]

[image]